# Resetar todos os campos (input,textarea) da página html

Tags: css, xhtml, textarea

Como posso fazer que através de um botão todos os textarea da página tenha seu conteúdo apagado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resetar todos os campos usando o método `reset()`. Segue um exemplo simples.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Primeiro nome: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Último nome: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Resetar form">
</form>
```

Fonte: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Comment: o mesmo não funciona para textarea? textarea também não seria form?
Porque eu testei no meu textarea e não reconhece essa função.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode adicionar um elemento `button` ou `input` com o `type="reset"`. Exemplo:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Primeiro nome: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Último nome: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br><br>
  <button type="reset">Resetar form</button>
</form>
```

O `textarea`, `input:checkbox`, `input:radio` e `select` não podem ser alterados dessa forma, somente com uma função do JS.

**Exemplo:**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
const reset = document.querySelector("#reset");

reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
  form.querySelectorAll("select,input,textarea").forEach((el) => {

    switch (true) {
      case el instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement:
        el.textContent = "";
      break;
      case el instanceof HTMLSelectElement:
        el.querySelectorAll("option").forEach( (el) => el.removeAttribute("selected"))
      break;
      case el.type == "checkbox":
      case el.type == "radio":
        el.removeAttribute("checked");
      break;
      default:
        el.value = "";
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Primeiro nome: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Último nome: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <textarea id="txt" name="txt">txt</textarea><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="radio" checked />
  <select name="select">
    <option value="Selecione algo">Selecione algo</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  

  <button type="reset" id="reset">Resetar form</button>
</form>
```